# JavaFx Webview showing garbage text

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine

I am opening some websites in JavaFx webview. All the sites are working fine but one of the sites is not opening correctly. All the english text is being displayed as special/unicode characters, but it is opening fine in Chrome, mozilla etc.

I am unable to figure out what the issue is with [this](http://www.snapdeal.com) particular site. Please help.

Comment: Did you ever fix this?